# Getting values after the key colon in xslt v2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've seen many related topics in the internet about getting the value after the colon or keys. So, what I did is, I applied all the possible solution provided by the xslt expert. But, upon combining the codes, I can't get the exact structure of the output. Here is my sample input file:

```
<Data>
   :A:00001
   :B:Sample Data Only B
   :C:082917
   :D2:Sample Data Only D1/090909
   :E2:Sample Data Only E1/121212
   :E2:Sample Data only E2/232323
   :D2:Sample Data Only D2/343434
   :E2:Sample Data Only E1/454545
   :F:092917

   :A:00002
   :B:Sample Data Only BB
   :C:053017
   :D2:Sample Data Only DD2/565656
   :E2:Sample Data Only EE1/676767
   :F:063017
</Data>
```

For :C: and :F:, they belong to the same level group `<AccountPeriod>`, but in my output it created another level group of `<AccountPeriod>` for :C: and :F:. For every occurrence of :D2:, it should create `<Detail>` group, and for each occurrence of :E:, it should create `<Group>` group inside `<Trans>` group. But, in my current output, it only gets all the value of :D: inside the `<Group>` elements instead of :E:. And lastly, my current output didn't iterate even if I have 2 occurrence of :A:. The tokenize(.,'\n\n') didn't work in my code.

Here is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\n\n')">
        <Data>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=":([0-9A-Za-z]+):(.*)\n">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:if test="regex-group(1)='A'">
                        <Line>
                            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                        </Line>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="regex-group(1)='B'">
                        <Number>
                            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                        </Number>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:variable name="SDate">
                        <xsl:if test="regex-group(1)='C'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                        </xsl:if>                            
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="EDate">
                        <xsl:if test="regex-group(1)='F'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                        </xsl:if>                            
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space($SDate)='') or not(normalize-space($EDate)='')">
                        <AccountPeriod>
                            <StartDate>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$SDate"/>
                            </StartDate>
                            <EndDate>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$EDate"/>
                            </EndDate>
                    </AccountPeriod>                            
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
            <xsl:variable name="temp" as="element()*">
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^:([D2][E2]):(.*)$" flags="m">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:element name="Detail{regex-group(1)}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$temp" group-starting-with="DetailD">
                <Detail>
                    <Seq>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(current-group()[1],'/')"/>
                    </Seq>
                    <Ext>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current-group()[1],'/')"/>
                    </Ext>
                        <Trans>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position() ge 2]">
                                <Group>
                                    <AcctNo>
                                         <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'/')"/> 
                                    </AcctNo>
                                    <Desc>
                                         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'/')"/> 
                                    </Desc>
                                </Group>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Trans>
                </Detail>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Data>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Current Output:

```
<Data>
   <Line>00001</Line>
   <Number>Sample Data Only B</Number>
   <AccountPeriod>
      <StartDate>082917</StartDate>
      <EndDate/>
   </AccountPeriod>
   <AccountPeriod>
      <StartDate/>
      <EndDate>092917</EndDate>
   </AccountPeriod>
   <Line>00002</Line>
   <Number>Sample Data Only BB</Number>
   <AccountPeriod>
      <StartDate>053017</StartDate>
      <EndDate/>
   </AccountPeriod>
   <AccountPeriod>
      <StartDate/>
      <EndDate>063017</EndDate>
   </AccountPeriod>
   <Detail>
      <Seq>090909</Seq>
      <Ext>Sample Data Only D1</Ext>
      <Trans>
         <Group>
            <DetailD2>Sample Data Only D2/343434</DetailD2>
         </Group>
         <Group>
            <DetailD2>Sample Data Only DD2/565656</DetailD2>
         </Group>
      </Trans>
   </Detail>
</Data>
```

Expected output:

```
<Record>
<Data>
    <Line>00001</Line>
    <Number>Sample Data Only B</Number>
    <AccountPeriod>
        <StartDate>082917</StartDate>
        <EndDate>092917</EndDate>
    </AccountPeriod>
    <Detail>
        <Seq>090909</Seq>
        <Ext>Sample Data Only D1</Ext>
        <Trans>
            <Group>
                <AcctNo>121212</AcctNo>
                <Desc>Sample Data Only E1</Desc>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <AcctNo>232323</AcctNo>
                <Desc>Sample Data Only E2</Desc>
            </Group>
        </Trans>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <Seq>343434</Seq>
        <Ext>Sample Data Only D2</Ext>
        <Trans>
            <Group>
                <AcctNo>454545</AcctNo>
                <Desc>Sample Data Only E1</Desc>
            </Group>
        </Trans>
    </Detail>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Line>00002</Line>
    <Number>Sample Data Only BB</Number>
    <AccountPeriod>
        <StartDate>053017</StartDate>
        <EndDate>063017</EndDate>
    </AccountPeriod>
    <Detail>
        <Seq>565656</Seq>
        <Ext>Sample Data Only DD2</Ext>
        <Trans>
            <Group>
                <AcctNo>676767</AcctNo>
                <Desc>Sample Data Only EE1</Desc>
            </Group>
        </Trans>
    </Detail>
</Data>
```

Your feedback is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45539795/3016153?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k - yes, I already applied and combined the codes that you have provided in the link and also in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523898/get-value-after-each-last-colon since the 2 problems are almost the same in my case. But, I can't get the correct structure of the output.

Comment: I don't think you have looked at it carefully enough. Otherwise you would have presented this as a grouping problem, where the starting point is the XML received here: http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrAh

Comment: Or the one here (i.e. after renaming): http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrAh/1. There are 3 separate problems here -  (a) converting the string to XML, (b) renaming the elements, and (c) grouping - and you should try and solve each problem in isolation as much as possible.